# Qt - QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I do have a QGridLayout and I want to make each element to be as close as it is possible to its neighbor.

Actually I have situation

[image: like this]

What should I do to to get the effect that I want (make it squeezed)? I have already tried a few things with spacing, margin, etc., but nothing helped.

And window before adding QGridLayout looks
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwCgV.png)

Comment: Have you tried other layouts?

Comment: What are the elements?

Comment: How do you define your requirement: _each element to be as close as it is possible to its neighbor_ ..

Comment: How about putting horizontal spacers to the left and right of your grid layout. And put that in another Horizontal or even vertical layout.

Comment: share your .ui..

Comment: Have you tried setting horizonal and vertical spacing to 0? http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#horizontalSpacing-prop

Comment: I think you have to set the property to not stretch, something like `grid->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed)` (or `::Expanding`, by default, I think). Not sure though.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen `stretch(int)` is something to do for specific column or row in the grid, not the grid as a whole.

Comment: @MohammadKanan It's not about `stretch(int)`, but about the (re)sizing policy. If `::Fixed`, when resized, the grid will retain its minimum size for the contents of the grid cell; if `::Expanding`, the cells will resize with the window.

Comment: @DanielWaechter Yes and it didn't help

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It also didn't help

Comment: @MohammadKanan I want there to be no gaps (nor vertical nor horizontal) between elements

Comment: @eyllanesc QPushButtons

Comment: @JamesSmith Just so there's no misunderstanding: `grid = new QTabWidget; grid->setSizePolicy(...)`. Is this what you tried? I admit, the naming can be misleading.

Comment: I would opt for [QFormLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qformlayout.html) in this case.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020491/qlabel-and-qpushbutton-align/49023510#49023510)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Are you sure you meant QTabWidget? I tried setting size policy for 'members' of this grid layout but it didn't work.

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes, as I did it in a small example, if you start with `QMainWindow` you have to have a central tab, to which you can add tabs, etc, but the tab has that property of resizing. To me, when I resize the window, the widgets inside don't resize. If a text label and a push button are in the grid, they stay to their minimum default size.

Comment: you need to set layoutSizeConstraint of gridlayout as SetMinAndMaxSize and Horizontal Policy, Vertical Policy as Preferred

Comment: @shahina Did it and to be honest I can't see any changes

Comment: Did you use any FixedSize for PushButtons

Comment: @shahina I checked setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed) and setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding) and Expanding looks better